# filelock allows opening of files

Tags: c, file, file-locking

i executed the following c code on my ubuntu machine...i have read about fcntl()'s use to lock a file and **even reading will not be allowed if F_WRLCK opton is set**...so i started this program and **before relinquishing the lock** by pressing enter i tried to open the file in two ways- by directly double clicking on file1.cpp  and by running a different c program in a new terminal...both the time the file was opened...so how did fcntl() allow opening of these files when F_WRLCK is set...

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

struct flock fl = {F_WRLCK, SEEK_SET,   0,      0,     0 };
int fd;

fl.l_pid = getpid();

if ((fd = open("/home/file1.cpp", O_WRONLY)) == -1)
{
    perror("open");
    exit(1);
}


if (fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW, &fl) == -1) 
{
    perror("fcntl");
    exit(1);
}


printf("Press <RETURN> to release lock: ");
getchar();

fl.l_type = F_UNLCK;  /* set to unlock same region */

if (fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &fl) == -1)
{
    perror("fcntl");
    exit(1);
}

printf("Unlocked.\n");

close(fd);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fcntl` locks are purely advisory locks. Their **only** effect is to cause `fcntl` `F_SETLK` calls to block when the lock cannot be obtained. They have absolutely no effect on IO operations. It's up to your program to obtain the locks it needs before performing IO when synchronization is necessary.

This is completely analogous to using mutexes to protect objects in memory. The mutex will not prevent you from reading or writing memory addresses; it's just a protocol you use to make sure your program only reads and writes and proper times.

Comment: @R..i don't understand...true fcntl() blocks till lock is not obtained but after the lock is obtained, shouldn't reading or writing to the file be prohibited for synchronisation, as i have obtained a write lock....if not then which function should be used

Comment: @R..i got it...just needed to read [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/linux-file-locking-types/) and your answer became clear